# How to show image with attributes?

Tags: php, image, magento

I want to attach image with attributes
for example i have manufacture attribute and i want to display image of manufacture on product view page, so my requirement is how can we add image field in attribute selection field in magento so admin can choose image for that manufacture attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several extensions (free or not) exist for that.

The one we use is free and on github here: [magento-attribute-option-image](https://github.com/jreinke/magento-attribute-option-image).